# c++ read in image set with different file names without hardcoding

Tags: c++, image, opencv, boost, image-loading

Is there any way of reading in a set of images from file that all have varying names to each other, i.e. no continuity at all?

So if you had 4 images in the same folder with the file names of:

1. **head.jpg**
2. **shoulders.png**
3. **knees.tiff**
4. **toes.bmp**

Without hard coding the file names directly, so you could change **shoulders.png** to say **arms.gif**, is there a way of loading them in?

I currently have OpenCV and Boost available

Comment: if you change **shoulders.png** to **arms.gif**, do you still need to know what body part it represents? or do you just need to load every image file located in a given directory?

Comment: with boost (or dirent.h from internet) you can get a list of all filenames in a specific folder. You can loop over all those filenames, then try to load the filename with opencv (imread) and test whether a image could be loaded (mat.empty() may not be true after loading). if an image could be loaded it is an image, if it wasnt successfuly just ignore that file.

Comment: Cheers sehe, but if I knew how I wouldn't have asked. The file names in the question are arbitrary. Thanks @Micka, I'll look into that.

Comment: So your question is actually : how to get the list of files in a directory ?

Comment: I guess technically yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else wondering:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
std::vector<cv::Mat> imageVec;
fs::path p ("."); 
fs::directory_iterator end_itr; 
// cycle through the directory
for (fs::directory_iterator itr(p); itr != end_itr; ++itr){
    // If it's not a directory, list it. If you want to list directories too, just remove this check.
    if (fs::is_regular_file(itr->path())) {
        if (fs::is_regular_file(itr->path())){
            cv::Mat img;
            img = cv::imread(itr->path().string());
            if(img.data) imagesVecc.push_back(img);
        }
        // assign current file name to current_file and echo it out to the console.
        std::string current_file = itr->path().string();
        std::cout << current_file << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well done. I had the frame done, but no experience with Gil/OpenCV :) (If you had made it clearer that you didn't need help there, you'd have had the answer sooner)